# Moving multiple files into multiple directories

Tags: linux, files, wildcards, mv

I have a directory as follows

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ualaoip2 mcm1    1073233 Sep 30 12:40 database.260.4-0.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 ualaoip2 mcm1  502373963 Sep 30 12:40 database.260.4-1.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 ualaoip2 mcm1  880379753 Sep 30 12:40 database.260.4-2.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x 2 ualaoip2 mcm1       4096 Sep 30 13:41 db0file
drwxr-xr-x 2 ualaoip2 mcm1       4096 Sep 30 13:41 db1file
drwxr-xr-x 2 ualaoip2 mcm1       4096 Sep 30 13:41 db2file
```

and I want to move the file `database...0` into `folder0` &c...

What's the best way of doing this? I tried various variants of

```
for i in $(ls fi*) do; mv $i ./folder$i
```

but they renamed things and overwrote lots of stuff I didn't want!

I tried using variants of

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | sort /* why is it not sorted?
```

but couldn't get rid of the . for the current directory.

I used mkdir db{0..7} to create the files - is this the best way?

I would appreciate a couple of words of explanation with the answer - not just a monkey see, monkey do! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you can depend on the filename format, there is your command:

```
for i in $(seq 0 2); do mv database*-"$i".tar.gz "db${i}file"/; done
```

There is the description. Your files appear to have stable format `database*-NUMBER.tar.gz` and the same number is in the directory name `dbNUMBERfile`. We can just generate numbers up to the highest (in this example 0..2 and run for cycle for these numbers. In case of database simple `$i` is sufficient as it's bordered with `-` and `.`, however `db$ifile` wouldn't work, as there is no `$ifile` variable defined. So we have to use curly brackets `db${i}file`, then the `$i` is properly resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
set -o nullglob

for name in database*-*[0-9].tar.gz; do
    num=${name##*-}
    num=${num%%.*}

    [ ! -d "folder$num" ] && mkdir "folder$num"

    mv "$name" "folder$num"
done
```

This will iterate over all the filenames that matches the `database*-*[0-9].tar.gz` pattern.

The `num` variable will be the number at the end of the filename (the number may be more than one digit) and it's picked out from the filename by first removing everything from the name up to and including the last `-`, and then removing the dot and everything afterwards.

The destination folders are created if they don't already exist.

By setting the `nullglob` shell option for `bash` first, we are guaranteed not to enter the loop at all if the pattern does not match any filenames.

---

You may change the pattern to just `database*.tar.gz` if you wish. I used a slightly more complicated pattern to be sure that all the components of the name are present that are actually used by the loop.